# How to print what i want here in Python like this picture

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I would like to print the dictionary `self.board` with the for loop, but I don't know how to make that.

What I want to print: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ9NU.png)

And here is my code:

```
class board:

    def __init__(self, length=3):
        v = '-'
        self.length = length
        self.size = self.length ** 2 + 1
        self.board = {k: v for k in range(1, self.size)}

    def check_board(self):
        print(self.board)

    def display_board(self):
        print("\nDisplay the board:")
        for i in range(1, self.length + 1):
            for k in range(1, self.length+1): # from here i dont know how to do the right thing to 
                                              # display like in the picture
                print(self.board[k] + " | ")
```

Comment: Now wrt/ the question itself: if you're "board" is supposed to be a grid, your data structure should reflect this one way or another (a list of lists comes to mind here...). As a general rule: getting the data structure right is the key to simple, easy, obvious code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made changes in your display function.

```
class Board:
  def __init__(self, length=3):
      v = '-'
      self.length = length
      self.size = self.length ** 2 + 1
      self.board = {k: v for k in range(1, self.size)}

  def check_board(self):
      print(self.board)

  def display_board(self):
      print("\nDisplay the board:")
      for i in range(1, self.length + 1):
          for k in range(1, self.length+1): # from here i dont know how to do the right thing to 
              if(k==self.length):
                print(" - ")
              else:                           # display like in the picture
                print(" - |",end="")
          print("")
```

Two noticable changes are using end="" which will not print it to new line. and then added a print("") to get to the new line after every row. The checking k==self.length is done for the last element for not printing "|"

Comment: And this is a perfect example of wrong design leading to overcomplicated (and less efficient) code... The proper solution being, of course, to fix the design instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using a more appropriate data structure makes for much simpler code:

```
class Board(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self._size = size
        self._board = [["-"] * self._size for i in range(self._size)]

    def display(self):
        print("\n".join("|{}|".format("|".join(row)) for row in b._board))
```